# HiSet text color for defaultLabel attribute in inplaceinput component for richfaces

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces

In richfaces for inplace input component `<rich:inplaceInput defaultLabel="click to edit">` there is a defaultLabel attribute(show default text if is no ouput) i want set color text for it,  i trying to set with `style=""` but dont know how to do it.

e.g for `value=""` i can set it via `style="margin-left:80;background-color:#fff...etc` but for this defaultlabel i cant set it, may i use styleClass and there i defined color text for default Text?
if is somebody who is familiar with css for advanced styling or knows use it in jsf,please let me post i'll be very grateful.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use `styleClass` for sure.

And in your CSS file define

```
.yourClass .rf-ii-dflt-lbl {
    color: red;
}
```

`.rf-ii-dflt-lbl` is the RichFaces-generated class for the default label.
In case the above is not working add `!important` to the rule:

```
color: red !important;
```

Comment: aha,thank you this look like a solution, and  also i want achevie by this way a showing outline in hover or mouseover in this rich faces input field,you know some css for this?

Comment: add `:hover` to the class name: `.yourClass .rf-ii-dflt-lbl:hover`, you may also want to use `:focus`